# How to fix Google Apps Script Function Running in random sequence

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a project that will generate a dynamic Listbox from GSheet and it will update the customized form i've created in Google Apps Script.

The code will get the input from the URL when it is loaded and generate 2 ListBox first before getting the input data to pre-fill the form.

So the Sequence should be

1. Generate the Selection for Car Brand
2. Generate the Selection for Colour
3. Get the customer data to pre-fill the form

But what I'm getting is whenever I refresh the page, the sequence of function loading is random. Sometimes it is working fine, sometimes it is loading **3 > 1 > 2** or **2 > 3 > 1** or any other random sequence.

Please suggest anyway that we can make sure the sequence is running as per design.

Below is the sample code

**Code.gs**

```
var SHEET_CAR_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet1ID}/edit#gid=0';
var SHEET_COLOUR_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet2ID}/edit#gid=0';
var SHEET_CUSTOMER_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet2ID}/edit#gid=0';


function doGet(request) {
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('CustomerForm').evaluate().setTitle("Demo Form");
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function loadCarList(){
  //load Cars GSheet
  var carsspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_CAR_URL).getSheetByName('Cars');
  numItemCars = carsspreadsheet.getLastRow()-1;// get the number of rows in the sheet
  colItemCars = carsspreadsheet.getLastColumn();// get the number of rows in the sheet
  listCarsArray = carsspreadsheet.getRange(2,1,numItemCars,colItemCars).getValues(); 

  var listCar = "<option value=''></option>";  
   for(var i=0; i<numItemCars; i++){
    listCar += "<option value='"+listCarsArray[i][0]+"'>"+listCarsArray[i][0]+"</option>";
  }
  Logger.log(listCar);
  return listCar;
}

function loadColourList(){
  //load Colour GSheet
  var colourspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_COLOUR_URL).getSheetByName('Colour');
  numItemColour = colourspreadsheet.getLastRow()-1;// get the number of rows in the sheet
  colItemColour = colourspreadsheet.getLastColumn();// get the number of rows in the sheet
  listColourArray = colourspreadsheet.getRange(2,1,numItemColour,colItemColour).getValues();

  var listColour = "<option value=''></option>";  
   for(var i=0; i<numItemColour; i++){
    listColour += "<option value='"+listColourArray[i][0]+"'>"+listColourArray[i][0]+"</option>";
  }
  Logger.log(listColour);
  return listColour;
}

function loadCustomer(inputID){
  //load Customer GSheet
  var customerspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_CUSTOMER_URL).getSheetByName('Customer');
  numItemCust = customerspreadsheet.getLastRow()-1;// get the number of rows in the sheet
  colItemCustr = customerspreadsheet.getLastColumn();// get the number of rows in the sheet
  listCustArray = customerspreadsheet.getRange(2,1,numItemCust,colItemCustr).getValues(); 

  var custDetails = [];
   for(var i=0; i<numItemCust; i++){
    var custID = listCustArray[i][0];
    var custName = listCustArray[i][1];
    var custArea = listCustArray[i][2];
    var custCar = listCustArray[i][2];
    var custCarColour = listCustArray[i][2];
    if(custID == inputID){
      custDetails = [custID,custName,custArea,custCar,custCarColour];
    }
  }
  Logger.log(custDetails[0]);
  return custDetails;
}
```

**CustomerForm.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body onload="myLoadFunction()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> Customer ID : </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="CustID"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Customer Name : </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="CustName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Customer Area : </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="CustArea"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Car Brand : </td>
        <td><select class='listbox' id='listCar' required></select> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Car Colour : </td>
        <td><select class='listbox' id='listColour' required></select> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
<script>

function myLoadFunction(){
    // Get the URL parameter
    google.script.url.getLocation(inputstrings => {
 
        let inputjson =  JSON.stringify(inputstrings.parameter);
        let inputparameters = JSON.parse(inputjson)
        var in_custID = inputparameters.id;
        alert('This is the ID '+in_custID);

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeCar).loadCarList(); 
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeColour).loadColourList(); 

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeForm).loadCustomer(in_custID); 

    })

    function initializeCar(inputList){
      alert('Loading Cars')
      document.getElementById('listCar').innerHTML = inputList;   
    }
    
    function initializeColour(inputList){
      alert('Loading Colour')
      document.getElementById('listColour').innerHTML = inputList;   
    }

    function initializeForm(inputDetails){
      alert('Loading Form')
      document.getElementById('CustID').value = inputDetails[0];
      document.getElementById('CustName').value = inputDetails[1];
      document.getElementById('CustArea').value = inputDetails[2];
      document.getElementById('listCar').value = inputDetails[3];
      document.getElementById('listColour').value = inputDetails[4];
    }
}

</script>
```

**Sample Customer Data**

| ID No | Customer Name | Customer Area | Car Brand | Car Colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Alice | IN | Toyota | Blue |
| 1002 | Bob | OH | Honda | Red |
| 1003 | Charlie | WD | BMW | Brown |

**Sample Colour**

| Colour |
| --- |
| Blue |
| Red |
| Brown |
| Green |
| Yellow |

**Sample Car Brand**

| Brand |
| --- |
| BMW |
| Toyota |
| Honda |
| Tesla |
| VW |

I've tried to use If Else to make sure the ListBox is already populated before running the 3rd function but no luck with that.

Thanks in Advance to anybody that can help in this.

Comment: I would consider combining all of the functions into one function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because google.script.run runs asynchronously, which means the second one doesn't wait for the first to return before running.  You need to nest them.  Then in the html `<script>` simply run the first only.  I've moved `in_custID` outside of the setLocation call so its available to the other functions.

```
function myLoadFunction(){
    // Get the URL parameter
    var in_custID = null;
    google.script.url.getLocation(inputstrings => {
 
        let inputjson =  JSON.stringify(inputstrings.parameter);
        let inputparameters = JSON.parse(inputjson)
        in_custID = inputparameters.id;
        alert('This is the ID '+in_custID);

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeCar).loadCarList(); 

    })

    function initializeCar(inputList){
      alert('Loading Cars')
      document.getElementById('listCar').innerHTML = inputList;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeColour).loadColourList(); 
    }
    
    function initializeColour(inputList){
      alert('Loading Colour')
      document.getElementById('listColour').innerHTML = inputList;   
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeForm).loadCustomer(in_custID); 
    }

    function initializeForm(inputDetails){
      alert('Loading Form')
      document.getElementById('CustID').value = inputDetails[0];
      document.getElementById('CustName').value = inputDetails[1];
      document.getElementById('CustArea').value = inputDetails[2];
      document.getElementById('listCar').value = inputDetails[3];
      document.getElementById('listColour').value = inputDetails[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried your method and it is having the similar result.

Tried refreshing the page a few times and I'm still getting the random sequence of running.

Comment: Then there is something else wrong with your process.  I have used this technique many times for similar situration and it has always worked for me.  The calls back on success for  `loadCarList` is `initializeCar` which then calls `loadColorList` whose call back on success is `initializeForm` so they have to run in that order.

Comment: Yup. i understand the logic behind the way you've suggested and did the changes to my code accordingly. But weirdly it is still running randomly. 

The above is the exact code I'm using for the demo purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you need to redeploy your app?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tips. I though once saved then it will take the updated code for /dev. But like what you've suggest. Will need to Re-deploy the app and run in /dev then it works. Thanks very much.